# Looking for a better way to show/hide an element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I'd like to know if someone could please show me a better way to show/hide an element on my page. This is how I am currently doing it.

At the very top of my index.php file, I have the code for my application. Here is the function which determines whether the form has been submitted and populates $_SESSION['prompt'] with data.

```
private function validateForm() {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $_SESSION['prompt'] = 'Form submitted';
    }
}
```

And here is the element which I would like to show/hide depending on whether the form has been submitted located towards the bottom of my index.php file.

```
<p id="dialog">
    <?php
        if (!empty($_SESSION['prompt'])) {
            echo $_SESSION['prompt'];
        }
        else {
            echo '<script>document.getElementById("dialog").style.display="none";</script>';
        }
    ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Why are you setting `$_SESSION` variables that you then use in the same file, as opposed to just variables?

Comment: Is there some reason you are not use AJAX to submit the form if you want to present a message to the user after the form gets submitted? I would look into jQuery and how to post a form via AJAX, I think it is the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hardly a great leap in creative logic to work that one out

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SESSION['prompt'])) {
        echo '<p id="dialog">'.$_SESSION['prompt'].'</p>';
    }
    else {
      // nothing
    }
?>
```

Why are you setting `$_SESSION` variables that you then use in the same file, as opposed to just variables? Are you using that data later?

Comment: Initially I did try to use a variable but could not echo it's value as it just returned nothing. For instance, right below my parent class I defined the public variable $prompt = ''; and within the private function validateForm() I had $this->prompt = "Form Submitted".

But like I said, I couldn't return the value for some reason. I had <?php echo $prompt; ?> within my element.

Comment: I put a little extra effort in and managed to figure out how to return a variable instead of a session variable. Turns out I had to echo $testApplication->prompt instead of $prompt.

Comment: `$this` would be used inside a class. You mean `$prompt='something'; echo $prompt;`